# Prevent electron-builder from packaging required node_modules

Tags: webpack, electron, electron-builder

I'm using `electron-builder` to build my `electron` application as a desktop app.
The build was fine, but its size was very large (68Mb).

When I used `asar explorer` to view my `app.asar` file. I realize that the `app.asar` file contains a folder named `node_modules`, in the `node_modules`, there are npm folders that have been bundled using `webpack`, such as: `angular`, `angular-messages`, `ui-cropper`, ...

[image: List of required folders]

How can I ignore those folder from being included in `app.asar` file ?

They have been bundled by `webpack` before.

Thank you

Comment: You want to build an electron app, which uses angular, but dont want webpack to bundle angular??? How do you expect the app to work?

Comment: I mean I use `webpack` to bundle those libraries, and I don't want to include the modules in  `node_modules` again, it increases my app size too much. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define which file will be included by using `"files"` section in `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "MyApp",
    ...
    "build": {
        "files": [
            "node_modules",
            "!node_modules/module-x/*" //prevent module x to be included
        ]
    }
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: What if I just want to include some specific node_modules and ignore the rest ? :)

Comment: Try this:
`{
    "name": "MyApp",
    ...
    "build": {
        "files": [
            "!node_modules", // ignore all
            "node_modules/module-x" // include module x
        ]
    }
    ...
}`